# UIView "Stuck", not responding to selectors

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm adding a custom `UIView` to my `HomeViewController`'s view like so:

```
var customView: CustomView!

func addCustomView() {
    customView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Int(view.frame.width), height: 150.0))
            customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            customView.delegate = self
            view.addSubview(customView)


    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0));
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-20-[view]-20-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["view": customView]));
}
```

This custom view has a button that segues to a modal view controller, and sets the current view controller as its delegate. When I dismiss the modal view controller, it calls its delegate method:

```
func modalVCDidCreateThing(thing: PFObject) {
    customView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

The `customView` is not being removed from the superview.

- I've checked that it's not `nil`
- After performing the `removeFromSuperview`, logging out the object shows that it still exists
- The code is running on the main thread
- The view doesn't respond to other commands either. For example, I tried setting it's `hidden` property to false, but the view does not hide. Logging out the view showed that the property was set.
- I tried `view.setNeedsLayout` after `removeFromSuperview`. Didn't work.

Super frustrated by this. Thanks.

Comment: can you please edit your questino and add more code, which is also relevant, like dismissing the modal viewcontroller and setting delegate and response to delegate methods etc. or full source code of both the view controllers, that will help more to understand your issue. thanks